# Raster Data calulation display on map

Tags: qgis, raster, slope

I want to be able to mark on a map areas in a ski resort that are a risk to avalanche. It is classified as such. "The slope between the contour lines are between 20 and 45 Degrees, The slope is facing towards the west."

How do i go about doing a calculation like this in QGIS? What is the tool that is to be used?

I presume I generate the slope by going to Raster -> Terrain Analyst -> slope and generate the slope of the map from my dem file(don't know if that the correct name, but that is the file I have). 
After this I am left with a black and white image. The white showing areas of higher slopes.
How do I cut this to only show the slopes between 20 and 45 and how to i check to see if its west facing.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that each thread should be limited to one specific question only. You can check our [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some common GIS operations. In order:

1. Create the map of slopes;
2. Create the map of aspect;
3. Use the raster calculator;
4. Save your result.

I will try to explain the above steps on this sample raster (it's a tile from a larger file):

[image]

**Step 1**

Go to `Raster` > `Terrain Analysis` > `Slope` and create your map of slopes using your dem as elevation layer (specify a path for your output layer and use the default parameters):

[image]

**Step 2**

Go to `Raster` > `Terrain Analysis` > `Aspect` and create your map of aspect using your dem as elevation layer (specify a path for your output layer and use the default parameters):

[image]

**Step 3**

Go to `Raster` > `Raster Calculator` and write this expression in the dialog that appears (remember also to specify the path where you want to save the output):

```
"slope@1" >= 20 AND "slope@1" <= 45 AND "aspect@1" >= 225 AND "aspect@1" <= 315
```

[image]

I'm assuming that `slope@1` is the raster of slopes and `aspect@1` is the raster of aspect and that "West" refers to all directions which have an orientation between 225° and 315° compared to the North. Once you have done this, you will obtain a raster with white and black cells: the white ones satisfy your criteria, while the black ones no.

[image]

**Step 4**

If you want to keep a raster output, you have nothing more to do. Otherwise, you may convert your raster to a shapefile going to `Raster` > `Conversion` > `Polygonize (Raster to Vector)...` and saving it to .shp format:

[image]